# Square roots in arbitrary fields

Tags: field-theory

I'm a little confused about a certain argument concerning square roots. The problem is Dummit and Foote, 13.2.9., detailed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30666/biquadratic-extension) with a solution also given.

Specifically my problem is as follows: suppose I have shown that $(\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n})^2=a+\sqrt{b}$. How should I then conclude that $\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}$?

I think I'm just a little confused about what the symbol $\sqrt{a}$ actually means in an arbitrary field. How do we make a choice between the two algebraically indistinguishable roots of $x^2-a$?

Thank you.

Comment: For an arbitrary field, there is (as far as I know) no way to make that distinction in a meaningful way (except in characteristic $2$, where there is only one choice).

Comment: If $b$ is non-zero, only one of the two square roots can satisfy the first equation. To get the second equation the roots have to be taken in a compatible way.

Comment: If $a\in F$ for a field $F$, then $\sqrt{a}$ is $\textbf{defined as}$ one root of $x^2-a$ which belongs to some field extension of $F$, namely the splitting field.

Comment: @pritam how can you define some thing as "one of" something?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I don't think it matters which one you choose, I mean the definition is not ambiguous. The other root is given by $-\sqrt{a}$. We also do this for defining say $n$th roots of unity, which are given by $1,\omega,\omega^2,\ldots ,\omega^{n-1}$, where $\omega $ is a primitive $n$th root of unity and there might be many primitive $n$th roots of unity.

Comment: @pritam how can it not be ambiguous when you don't specify which one you choose? Note that we don't use some symbol to refer to "a primitive $n$'th root of unity" but actually write that whole thing.

Comment: Note also that there is an automorphism fixing the ground field which exchanges the square roots. As I noted in my previous comment, once the choice is made it has to be made consistently. The automorphism effectively shows that the two choices are equivalent. Changing the sign of $\sqrt a$ on the right hand side would mean changing the left-hand side too - applying the same automorphism to both sides to retain equality.

Comment: @MarkBennet But note that if we instead restrict to those element that are already squares, then not all choices of squareroot are equally "good" (as only some choices will lead to $\sqrt{}$ being a homomorphism of the groups of units).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, formulations such as

> Suppose $a^2-b$ is a square where $a,b\in F$ and $b$ is not a square. Show that $\sqrt{a+\sqrt b}=\sqrt m+\sqrt n$ for some $m,n\in F$

are to some degree an abuse of notation when the field is not $\mathbb R$ (or a subfield thereof). There are also problems *if* the field is $\mathbb R$ and roots of negative numbers are to be taken (as is the case here as $b$ is explicitly not a square).  A more adequate formulation might be

> Suppose $a^2-b$ is a square where $a,b\in F$ and $b$ is not a square. Show that there exist $m,n\in F$ such that $F[X,Y]/(X^2-m,Y^2-n)$ has an element $\gamma$ such that $(\gamma^2-a)^2=b$.

But this is probably less appealing to read.
Just keep in mind that oneshould, in this context, take $\sqrt a$ to mean "for all $\alpha$ with $\alpha^2=a$" or "there exists $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^2=a$", depending on where in the statement the square root occurs. Thus:

> For all $\beta$ with $\beta^2=b$ and all $\gamma$ with $\gamma^2=a+\beta$ there exist $m,n\in F$ and $\mu,\nu$ with $\mu^2=m$ and $\nu^2=n$ and $\gamma=\mu+\nu$.

or

> For all $\beta$ with $\beta^2=b$  there exist $m,n\in F$ and $\mu,\nu$ with $\mu^2=m$ and $\nu^2=n$ and $(\mu+\nu)^2=a+\beta$.

In both cases, "in a suitable extension field of $F$" or "in $\overline F$" should be added for all those greek letters. Thus by the end of the day, the "abusive" notation as originally given is nicely concise and is fine as long as one watches out for sign problems.

Comment: This precise formulation will be very useful to bear in mind. In particular I appreciate seeing all the required quantifiers. Thank you for your thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would get two answers: $\sqrt{(\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n})^2} = \pm \sqrt{a + \sqrt{b}}$. However, the negative solution you can drop here because $\sqrt{m}$ and $\sqrt{n}$ are already positive, by definition of the symbol $\sqrt{~}$, so you cannot get the negative root $-\sqrt{a + \sqrt{b}}$ as solution if you want $\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n}$ and not $-(\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: The field is arbitrary, positive and negative are not defined.

Comment: If you actually use the $\sqrt{}$ symbol, you should never mean more than one number. And this really does not answer the question actually asked, which is about arbitrary fields.